# How do we constrain the layout of two Views to have the same position and size in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swiftui, nslayoutconstraint, swiftui-view

I am a mildly experienced UIKit/AppKit developer, but I am just getting started using SwiftUI. In UIKit it is straight forward to constrain two `UIView`'s to have the same size and position using interface builder or programmatically using `NSLayoutConstraint`s. Using SwiftUI's declarative approach should make this easier, but I find myself having to manually determine the frame size and position so I feel I am missing something.

As an example, say I want to create the `View` hierarchy shown in figure below. The main goal is to create a transparent `CanvasView` instance that lies over the top of an `ImageView` whose size and placement has been tailored to display the image with the correct aspect ratio.

[image]

Currently I can accomplish this by wrapping the contents of the `ZStack` inside
a `GeometryReader` and then do the layout math by hand and explicitly setting
the frame size and position of both the `ImageView` and `CanvasView`

```
struct WidgetView: View {
    let uiimage = UIImage(named: "cateyes")!
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Button("Left", action: {print("do left")})
                Spacer()
                Button("Right", action: {print("do right")})
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            ZStack(alignment: .center) {
                GeometryReader { geom in
                    let aspect = uiimage.size.width / uiimage.size.height
                    let w = geom.size.width
                    let h = geom.size.width / aspect
                    let fits = h <= geom.size.height
                    let s = fits ? 1.0 : geom.size.height / h
                    let W = s*w
                    let H = s*h
                    let x0 = (geom.size.width - W)/2
                    ImageView(uiimage: uiimage)
                        .frame(width: W, height: H, alignment: .top)
                        .position(x: x0 + W/2, y: H/2)
                    CanvasView()
                        .frame(width: W, height: H, alignment: .top)
                        .position(x: x0 + W/2, y: H/2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ImageView` simply contains a scaled view of the image that maintains its
aspect ratio:

```
struct ImageView: View {
    var uiimage : UIImage!
    var body: some View {
        Image(uiImage: uiimage)
            .resizable()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
    }
}
```

The `CanvasView` in this example merely draws an X from the corners of its view

```
struct CanvasView: View {
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            let w = geometry.size.width
            let h = geometry.size.height
            Path { path in
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0,y: 0))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h))
                path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: h))
                path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: 0))
            }
            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 4)
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to work in this example, but I should not have to explicitly compute the layout. I am also concerned that the containing `ZStack` will not resize itself
correctly when this is done. Is there a more direct way to constrain two views to have the same frame (and other possible constraints) like we do in UIKit?

[image]

You can find the above solution on [github](https://github.com/wcochran/image-canvas-view).

Comment: I would suggest making the ```CanvasView``` an ```.overlay``` over the ```ImageView```. An overlay (and also a background layer) automatically adopts the same frame as the view it is applied to.

Comment: @BenzyNeez when I add `.overlay(CanvasView())` to the `ImageView()` the frame size is not the same (it is larger). How do I enforce the overlayed View to be exactly the same size?

Comment: OK, maybe you just need to force ```CanvasView``` to use all the space available, this being the full frame size of the underlying view. You can apply ```.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)``` to ```CanvasView``` to do this.

Comment: @BenzyNeez the `CanvasView` ends up being larger (fills the remaining content). I do note that adding the `.overlay` works when I add the same frame position and size I computed as before (I also suppose this obviates the need for a `ZStack`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick up on my comments, I would suggest making the `CanvasView` an `.overlay` over the `ImageView`. An overlay automatically adopts the same frame as the view it is applied to (as does a background layer).

Here is a revised version of your example to show it working. I also changed `UIImage` to `Image` and used a `Canvas` for drawing the X.

```swift
struct WidgetView: View {
    let image = Image("cateyes")
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            HStack {
                Button("Left", action: {print("do left")})
                Spacer()
                Button("Right", action: {print("do right")})
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 8)
            ImageView(image: image)
                .overlay { CanvasView() }

            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ImageView: View {
    let image: Image
    var body: some View {
        image
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
    }
}

struct CanvasView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Canvas { context, size in
            let w = size.width
            let h = size.height
            var path = Path()
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: h))
            path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: h))
            path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: w, y: 0))
            context.stroke(path, with: .color(.black), style: .init(lineWidth: 4))
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Eyes]

Comment: Much simpler. Only thing is that the image is no longer horizontally centered in landscape mode.

Comment: That's because your ```VStack``` has leading alignment. Try removing the alignment.